# Can you tell when the secret_id will expire in Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

I recently updated an AppRole secret_id using the following command

```
vault write -tls-skip-verify auth/approle/role/my-super-role-name/secret-id secret_id_ttl=4320h
```

How can I know when that secret-id will expire?

Since I ran the command I know that it will expire in 4320h hours, but is there a way to check the expiration if you didn't create it?

I know you can check secret_id_ttl using

```
vault read -tls-skip-verify auth/approle/role/my-super-role-name/secret-id-ttl

Key              Value
---              -----
secret_id_ttl    4320h
```

But that only shows how much it was set to initially it doesn't serve as a count down.

Comment: You can do this for remaining token duration, but I do not believe this is available for secret id remaing duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print info about `creation_time, expiration_time, last_updated_time` of specified secret-id:
https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/approle#read-approle-secret-id

Comment: @outflack thanks that worked. It provided me with `creation_time` , `expiration_time` , `last_updated_time` among other info

Answer (score 0):

You can call lookup path API

```
vault write auth/approle/role/<role-name>/secret-id/lookup secret_id=<secret-id>

Key                   Value
---                   -----
cidr_list             <value>
creation_time         <value>
expiration_time       <value>
last_updated_time     <value>
metadata              <value>
secret_id_accessor    <value>
secret_id_num_uses    <value>
secret_id_ttl         <value>
token_bound_cidrs     <value>
```